# CodeIgniter Ion_auth check login

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, ion-auth

how can i check if user logged in or not **in view** ??

something like this:

```
if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in())
{
    // do something ..
}
else
{
    // do something else ..
}
```

and how can i get user data to variable ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

In your controller, you can do something like

```
function some_method() {
    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
      $loggedin = true;
    } else {
      $loggedin = false;
    }

    $data['loggedin'] = $loggedin;

    $this->load->view('some_view.php', $data);
}
```

and then in your view

```
<?php if ($loggedin): ?>
    <p>Logged in</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Please log in</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Alternatively, you could just load a different view from your controller if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 2):

As stealthyninja said, it should be performed in the controller. You can cut down on the amount of code in your controllers by extending the base CodeIgniter controller, and then have your controller for authenticated areas of your project extend your custom controller. Your custom controller could have a constructor that checks whether or not the user is authenticated and route them appropriately. This same constructor could also set variables within so as to be easily accessible by the custom controller's subclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. More info in "Extending Core Class" section on this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$this->ion_auth->logged_in() ? $data['logged'] = true : $data['logged'] = false;

$this->load->view('index', $data);
```

View:

```
<?php if ($logged): ?>
    do something...
<?php else: ?>
    do something else...
<?php endif; ?>
```